# Convert the Number to binary using IEEE 754 standard (32-bits)

Tags: binary, numbers, 32-bit, ieee-754, ieee

I am trying to convert the number -11.25 to binary using IEEE 754 standard 32- bits.

This is what i got so far:

-11.25 = 1011.0100

1.0110100 * 2^3 
    3 + 127 = 130

```
= 1.0110100 * 2130
```

IEEE 754 standard = 1 10000010 1011010...0

I think that my answer is wrong but i can't figure out were.

Comment: Are you looking for just convertion or fer detailed explanations ?

Comment: I am looking for further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i will assume you already know the Standard we can convert as following ,

Convert your number to base 2

`1011.01000`
Shift this binary number

`1.01101000`

`2**3` (shifted by 3)

add exponent 127+3=130

convert 130 to binary format `10000010`

And so we have `sign * 2^exponent * mantissa`

`Sign` which is obviously negative here , so the sign bit will be `1`

2^3 (since 3 was your exponent and it will result 130 that we convert to binary) will be `10000010`

and the mantissa here will be `01101000000000000000000`

your final result is `1|10000010|01101000000000000000000`

Comment: awesome, and one more question, do i put the hidden bit in the answer or is not necessary ?

Comment: @Marga You should omit it as it can be calculated from the exponent , this allows one more bit of precision in the mantissa .(don't forget to accept the answer if that's what you were looking for)

Comment: Thanks Kiloreux for the help, it really help me.

Comment: You can check your answers to conversions like these with an online floating-point converter (like mine, at http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ (check the 'Single', 'Normalized binary scientific notation', and 'Raw Binary' boxes)).